# Opening .pdf files using a <a href> link

Tags: jsf, pdf, hyperlink

I have a .pdf document in a folder called docs, that is inside of my WebContent folder.

I want to have a link to show the address to this file, so that when the user click it, he can see the document's content.

**The code is this:**

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/Web/docs/jsftutorial.pdf">See document</a>
```

**When I execute it, I get the error:**

```
HTTP Status 404 - /Web/docs/jsftutorial.pdf
```

I tested this with a .txt file, and it works, but why not with a .pdf?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tutorial on how to Read and open the PDF in a new browser window here:

http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/2006/05/pdf-handling.html

Now it works!